# Unable to open lsml files in VS2013 -there is no designer support for this file

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I was working on the lightswitch application using VS2013 and suddenly started getting this error: "there is no designer support for this file".

I repaired the installation of the VS2013, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Visual Studio there is an option to install Lightswitch.  Go to Control Panel -> Programs and do a Configure if possible or alternatively find the original installer and re-run it to check if the Lightswitch option was/is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did select Lightswitch, it worked for some time. and then suddenly I started getting this error.